# Unable to view locals in Eclipse + EPIC

Tags: eclipse, perl, epic

I just installed the Perl EPIC plugin for Eclipse 3.7. The debugger itself is working fine and I can step through my code. However I am unable to see any variables. Eclipse is reporting this error in the Error Log:

> An error occurred while parsing debugger variables; contents of the
>   Variables view may be inaccurate. Failure caused by string:
>   {NS00000003$^AS00000002''NS00000003$^DS000000010NS00000003$^ES00000043'The
>   system could not find the environment option that was
>   entered'NS00000003$^FS000000012NS00000003$^HS00000003256NS00000003$^LS00000003''NS00000003$^OS00000009'MSWin32'NS00000003$^PS00000003831NS00000010$^RE_TRIE_MAXBUFS0000000565536NS00000003$^SS000000011NS00000007$^TAINTS000000010NS00000009$^UNICODES000000010NS00000003$^VS00000007v5.10.0

There's a whole lot more which is just a bit much to be posting here so I've posted it over on PasteBin here:

> http://pastebin.com/k9kyhX0U

My perl script is pretty basic stuff:

```
$x = "hello world";
print "$x";
```

I'm running:

- Eclipse 3.7
- EPIC 0.5.46 - downloaded and installed via the Eclipse software manager from http://www.epic-ide.org/updates/
- ActiveState Perl: v5.10.0 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
- Windows 7 Ultimate x64

I've made sure PadWalker is installed and working properly.

I also checked to make sure this wasn't an issue and it isn't (`Cwd.pm` is fixed).

> http://www.epic-ide.org/faq.php#debug

What could be wrong?

Comment: Although this is old, the PadWalker documentation implies to me that variables must be lexical which means these have to have scope.  That can only happen if declared with the my keyword.   Perhaps that was the issue all along.

Comment: @shawn1874 thanks for the comment, but I've long since moved on and fortunately no longer have to go near perl or Eclipse :)

Comment: that is good for you then.  I'm not thrilled about having to learn Perl myself but I have to maintain some old scripts for now.  I believe that I've answered my own question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72020665 which could also be the same answer for this question. Perhaps that will help someone else someday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer appears to lie in the module documentation for PadWalker which states, "PadWalker is a module which allows you to inspect (and even change!) lexical variables in any subroutine which called you. **It will only show those variables which are in scope at the point of the call.**"

Moreover, the PERL-EPIC documentation for Eclipse indicates that it relies on PadWalker to provide a debug capability.  Therefore the ability to inspect variables in the Eclipse debugger using that specific plugin depends on explicitly declaring variables. The key point is that the use of the my keyword is what declares a variable with lexical scope.

You can see in the image here that the variables show up when declared.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Shawn...this seems to make sense, though I have no desire to validate :)

Answer (score 1):

As a wild guess, I'd suggest checking to make sure the location of your perl.exe is specified to Eclipse, and that your %PATH% variable references it. If you're unable to solve the issue, I'd highly recommend Padre (http://padre.perlide.org). Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks. Eclipse knows where perl.exe is and can hit breakpoints just fine, it's just unable to show variables. I'll give Padre a spin though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the "testing" EPIC version. version 6.41